Using interdependent 2 sat to find if a possible number is valid in sudoku
Has there been any papers or books covering using 2sat in an interdependent way to find if a possible number in a sudoku cell is valid.
What I have so far is this off the ai I wanted to read more on the topic.

Reduction to 2SAT:
Let's consider a Sudoku puzzle of size n × n. We represent each cell in the grid as a set of n Boolean variables: x_i_j_k, where i and j are the row and column indices (1 ≤ i, j ≤ n), and k is the possible value (1 ≤ k ≤ n) for that cell.

We create the following clauses:
a) At least one value per cell:
(x_i_j_1 OR x_i_j_2 OR ... OR x_i_j_n) for all i, j
b) At most one value per cell:
(NOT x_i_j_k OR NOT x_i_j_l) for all i, j, k, l where k ≠ l
c) Row Constraint:
(NOT x_i_j_k OR NOT x_i_l_k) for all i, k, j, l where j ≠ l
d) Column Constraint:
(NOT x_i_j_k OR NOT x_l_j_k) for all j, k, i, l where i ≠ l
e) Block Constraint:
(NOT x_i_j_k OR NOT x_p_q_k) for all k and i, j, p, q in the same √n × √n block, where (i,j) ≠ (p,q)
f) Given Values:
(x_i_j_k) for each cell (i,j) initially filled with value k

Complexity Analysis:
The number of variables is O(n^3), as we have n^2 cells, each with n possible values.
The number of clauses is O(n^4):


O(n^2) clauses for (a)
O(n^4) clauses for (b)
O(n^4) clauses each for (c), (d), and (e)
O(n^2) clauses at most for (f)

The reduction process itself runs in O(n^4) time, as we need to generate all these clauses.

Solving 2SAT:
The 2SAT problem can be solved in linear time with respect to the number of variables and clauses using the strongly connected components algorithm (Aspvall, Plass & Tarjan, 1979).

In our case, this means the 2SAT solver runs in O(n^4) time.

Overall Time Complexity:
The total time complexity is O(n^4) for the reduction plus O(n^4) for solving 2SAT, which is O(n^4) overall.

Correctness:
If the 2SAT instance is satisfiable, the satisfying assignment directly corresponds to a valid Sudoku solution. If it's unsatisfiable, the original Sudoku puzzle has no solution.

Uniqueness:
This method finds a solution if one exists but doesn't guarantee uniqueness. To check for uniqueness, we could solve the 2SAT instance, then add a clause negating this solution and resolve. If the second instance is unsatisfiable, the original solution was unique.


I have an idea of how it might be possible to get that closer to O x^3. So any good books or papers of 2 sat recommendations in this or near this area that might help would be good.
Note when I say interdependent 2sat which this is about I mean multiple 2 sats that effect each other when something is done in the one 2 sat the others are effected. There isn't a standard term for this but it has apparently been tested on completing sudoku but I'm not sure if it's been used with validating a possibility in a sudoku cell which apparently is quicker for big grids.
Interdependent 2-SAT and 2-SAT are both variants of the Boolean satisfiability problem (SAT), but they differ in the nature of the clauses involved.
2-SAT:

Independent Clauses: Each clause contains exactly two literals (e.g., (A, B) or (¬A, ¬B)).
No Dependencies: The clauses are independent of each other. Satisfying one clause does not directly affect the satisfaction of others.
Interdependent 2-SAT:
Dependent Clauses: Each clause contains exactly two literals, but the clauses can be dependent on each other.
Dependencies: Satisfying one clause might make it harder or easier to satisfy others. This can create cycles and dependencies between clauses.
Key Differences:
Dependencies: The primary difference lies in the presence of dependencies between clauses. In 2-SAT, clauses are independent, while in interdependent 2-SAT, clauses can be interconnected.
Complexity: Interdependent 2-SAT is generally more challenging to solve than 2-SAT due to the added complexity of dependencies and potential cycles.
Algorithms: While both 2-SAT and interdependent 2-SAT can be solved using SAT solvers, specialized algorithms might be more efficient for interdependent 2-SAT due to its unique characteristics.
In summary: While both 2-SAT and interdependent 2-SAT involve clauses with two literals, interdependent 2-SAT introduces the additional complexity of dependencies between clauses, making it a more challenging problem to solve.

Interdependent 2 sats are in p time with the special class bounded tree widths and finding if a number in a sudoku cell is valid is special class bounded tree widths.

Please [edit] your question to elaborate on what you are asking.  What are "interdependent 2sat reductions"?  Please define all non-standard terms.  What does it mean for a "possible number" to be "valid"?

The clauses in (a) do not have 2 literals, but $n$ literals. Thus this is not a reduction to 2-SAT, but to general CNF-SAT.
